# SQL Problems : Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, join, subquery

**GOAL**

I simply want to select the details of those employees having salary greater then the HCL(company-employe).

[image: Tables]

**What I've tried :**

```
SELECT Emp.emp_id, Emp.Emp_name, Department.dept_name, Emp.Salary, Company.company_name from emp 
 JOIN department ON(emp.emp_id=department.emp_id) 
  JOIN company ON(department.dept_id=company.dept_id) 
   where emp.salary > (SELECT Emp.Salary FROM emp where Company.company_name='HCL');
```

**Problem :**

When I'm executing this query it shows : **Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row :**

**To remove the above error, I've tried :**

```
SELECT Emp.emp_id, Emp.Emp_name, Department.dept_name, Emp.Salary, Company.company_name from emp 
     JOIN department ON(emp.emp_id=department.emp_id) 
      JOIN company ON(department.dept_id=company.dept_id) 
       where emp.salary > (SELECT Emp.Salary FROM emp where Company.company_name='HCL' LIMIT 1);
```

I know that by providing *LIMIT* to the query it doesn't provides the desired output but it removes the Subquery returns more than 1 row error and when i executed this query it provides blanks rows and column at the output.

So anyone can help me where and what i am lacking in the query to select the desired details..

Comment: Does HCL have only one employee?

Comment: `company.company_name` does not seem defined.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
select 
    e.emp_id, 
    e.emp_name, 
    d.dept_name, 
    e.salary, 
    c.company_name 
from emp e
inner join department d on e.emp_id = d.emp_id
inner join company c on d.dept_id = c.dept_id
where e.salary > (
    select max(e1.salary)
    from emp e1 
    inner join company c1 on c1.dept_id = e1.dept_id
    where c1.company_name = 'HCL'
);
```

This will give you the employees that have a salary greater than all salaries of company HCL.

Comment: where e.salary > (
    select max(e1.salary)
    from emp e1 
    inner join company c1 on c1.dept_id = e1.emp_id
    where c1.company_name = 'HCL'
);

Comment: i am using JOIN (and you corrected : inner join) in the query is this makes some changes

Comment: @AjStyles: `inner join` and `join` are just synonyms, no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

`company.company_name` doesn't look right, but some databases do support nested record structures in rows.  I assume that your database does.

I would suggest that you want one of the following:

```
-- greater than the average
where emp.salary > (select avg(Emp.Salary)
                    from emp 
                    where Company.company_name = 'HCL'
                   );

-- greater than all
where emp.salary > (select max(Emp.Salary)
                    from emp 
                    where Company.company_name = 'HCL'
                   );

-- greater than any
where emp.salary > (select min(Emp.Salary)
                    from emp 
                    where Company.company_name = 'HCL'
                   );
```

Comment: Sir, it is a matter of great pride for me that you have answered my question. I got to learn a lot from your previous answers on stockoverflow but this answer is also provides blanks rows and column at output..

Comment: The above answer of @GMB helps me